# How to scrape badly formed HTML

Tags: html, screen-scraping

I'm trying to scrape a really really old page that looks like it was built with FrontPage or even just pasted from a Word document. It's full of font tags that can spontaneously stop and start in the middle of a word, or similar elements at randomly different tree depths.

I am not looking for any tools that can parse poor XML, I am already using [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). When I say badly formed HTML I mean it was not outputted from a database, does not have any consistent patterns, but on the screen it looks fine.

What techniques and tools can I use?

Comment: http://htmlpurifier.org/

Comment: @happygilmore What language are you scraping with? If you're in a browser, you can set that poorly-written XML as the contents of another element and let the browser straighten it out. If you're using a server-side language, you can often times create an ad-hoc DOM from the source, and then crawl that.

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with HTML, since you've taken care of that problem.  Your problem is figuring out how to pull data out of human-readable stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [cheerio](https://github.com/MatthewMueller/cheerio) in Nodejs. It replicates the same api as jQuery which makes it very easy to parse bad formatted html. Scraping with Javascript makes sense for many reasons.

This is an example taken from [node.io](https://github.com/chriso/node.io),

```
var request = require('request')
  , cheerio = require('cheerio')
  , async = require('async')
  , format = require('util').format;

var reddits = [ 'programming', 'javascript', 'node' ]
  , concurrency = 2;

async.eachLimit(reddits, concurrency, function (reddit, next) {
    var url = format('http://reddit.com/r/%s', reddit);
    request(url, function (err, response, body) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var $ = cheerio.load(body);
        $('a.title').each(function () {
            console.log('%s (%s)', $(this).text(), $(this).attr('href'));
        });
        next();
    });
});
```